# Find the exact value of $\sin(\pi+\alpha)+\cos(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha)+\tan(-\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Given that $\tan(\alpha) = -3$ find the exact value of $$
\sin(\pi + \alpha) + \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha\right) + \tan\left(-\frac \pi 2+\alpha\right).
$$

I tried:

$$\sin(\pi+\alpha)+\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha\right)+\tan\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha\right)  \\
=(\sin(\pi)\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\pi)\sin(\alpha))+\left(\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\cos(\alpha)-\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\sin(\alpha)\right)+\tan\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha\right)  \\
=-\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\alpha)+\frac{\tan(-\frac{\pi}{2})+\tan(\alpha)}{1-\tan(-\frac{\pi}{2})\tan(\alpha)} \\
=\frac{\tan(-\frac{\pi}{2})+\tan(\alpha)}{1-\tan(-\frac{\pi}{2})\tan(\alpha)} \\
=\frac{-\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})-3}{1-(-\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})(-3)} \\
=\frac{-\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})-3}{1-3\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})}  \\
= ???$$

What do I do next?

Comment: It is also known that $\tan\alpha=-3$. Maybe you mean, "given that $\tan\alpha=-3$?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Same thing, isn't it? I'll edit it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the first two terms cancel out. However, the third term *cannot* be evaluated using the known formula, since both numerator and denominator are infinite. This is a mistake that must be kept in mind for these kinds of problems.

Instead, consider the following chain of statements:
$$
\tan \left(-\frac \pi 2 + \alpha \right) = - \tan\left(\frac \pi 2 - \alpha\right),
$$
which follows from $\tan(-x) = -\tan(x)$ for all $x$. At this point, we note that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha) \neq 0$. Indeed, if this were not true, then $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha) = 0$ implies that $\alpha$ is of the form $n\pi$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$. However, in this case, $\tan(\alpha) =0$ is always true, providing a contradiction to $\tan(\alpha) = -3$.

Therefore, we write $$
- \tan\left(\frac \pi 2 - \alpha\right) = -\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha\right)}{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha\right)} = - \frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)} = -\cot(\alpha),
$$
where we used the extremely common identity and its twin $$
\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha\right) = \sin(\alpha), \text{and} \\
\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha\right) = \cos(\alpha).
$$
Now, it follows that
$$
-\cot \alpha = \frac{-1}{\tan \alpha} = \frac{-1}{3},
$$
providing an answer to the question. The important fact here to notice is that one cannot use the tangent sum identity if one of the summands is of the form $n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$, points at which the tangent is undefined. However, using the aforementioned identities and writing the tangent as the ratio of the sine and cosine, one can always transform such expressions to involve only the variable at hand, helping solve the problem.

Comment: How do you know that $- \tan\left(\frac \pi 2 - \alpha\right) = -\cot \alpha$ ?

Comment: It is a well known identity that $\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha\right) = \cot \alpha$. For derivations (and nice ones!) you can see here: http://www.math-only-math.com/trigonometrical-ratios-of-90-degree-minus-theta.html

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: You  are welcome! The upshot of the whole argument is that one can't apply the sum/difference formula for tan when one of the angles is $\frac \pi 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Simply,

$$\sin(\pi + \alpha)=-\sin \alpha$$
$$\cos(\frac{3\pi}{2} + \alpha)=\sin\alpha$$
$$\tan(-\frac{\pi}{2} + \alpha)=-\cot \alpha$$

Now, By drawing triangle. $-\sin \alpha=\frac{-3}{\sqrt{10}}$,$\sin\alpha=\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$ and $\cot \alpha=\frac{1}{3}$. Rest is simple arithmatics.

Assumptions: $\tan \alpha=3$

Answer (score 2):

- $\sin(\pi+\alpha)=-\sin\alpha$,
- $\cos\bigl(\frac{3\pi}2+\alpha\bigr)=\sin\alpha$,
- $\tan\bigl(-\frac\pi2+\alpha\bigr)=-\dfrac1{\tan\alpha}$, so
  $$\sin(\pi+\alpha)+\cos\bigl(\tfrac{3\pi}2+\alpha\bigr)+\tan\bigl(-\tfrac\pi2+\alpha\bigr)=-\dfrac1{\tan\alpha}=\frac13.$$